# React Navigation - Empty screen after closing the app and click on back

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I'm using react-navigation(v4) with the following structure.

**Switch Navigator**

```
export const RootNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    naoLogado: { screen: NaoLogadoNavigator },
    logado: { screen: PrincipalDrawerNavigator }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "naoLogado"
  }
)
```

Then, on **NaoLogadoNavigator** I have the following:

```
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack"

export const NaoLogadoNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    cadastro: { screen: CadastroScreen },
    login: { screen: LoginScreen },
    onboard: { screen: OnboardScreen },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "onboard",
  }
)
```

The problem happens when:
1. From Onboard Screen I navigate to Login
2. Close the App
3. Click on the Back at the Header of Navigation
4. Blank screen appears

**Step 1**

[image]

**Step 2**

[image]

**Step 3 - Closing the app**

[image]

**Step 4 - Open again and touching on Back**

[image]

**SOLVED - RESOLUTION BELOW**

Firstly thanks to [Gaurav-Roy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11355303/gaurav-roy) for his time helping me.

On **NaoLogadoNavigator** I changed the createStackNavigator to createNativeStackNavigator from react-native-screens/createNativeStackNavigator. The final version of file seems like this now:

```
import createNativeStackNavigator from "react-native-screens/createNativeStackNavigator"

export const NaoLogadoNavigator = createNativeStackNavigator(
  {
    cadastro: { screen: CadastroScreen },
    login: { screen: LoginScreen },
    onboard: { screen: OnboardScreen },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "onboard"
  }
)
```

Comment: okay , so when you open the app again which screen do you land on? and can you share your code on expo snack? so that ill check and revert

Comment: I open in the latest screen opened by the user. Hmm, I'm not using expo to build it. There is another way to you see it?

Comment: like you dont need expo for me to see on expo snack, you can copy past the code there so that i can check , with all proper imports

Comment: Ok, the code you need to know is the screen files? Or what file is it?

Comment: One quick update. I changed the import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack" to import createNativeStackNavigator from "react-native-screens/createNativeStackNavigator"
And it worked. Don't understand why.

Comment: woah, great. do tell me the reason if you get to know

Comment: I'll. Thanks for your time Gaurav!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED - ALSO EDITED ON THE QUESTION**

Firstly thanks to [Gaurav-Roy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11355303/gaurav-roy) for his time helping me.

On NaoLogadoNavigator I changed the createStackNavigator to createNativeStackNavigator from react-native-screens/createNativeStackNavigator. The final version of file seems like this now:

```
import createNativeStackNavigator from "react-native-screens/createNativeStackNavigator"

export const NaoLogadoNavigator = createNativeStackNavigator(
  {
    cadastro: { screen: CadastroScreen },
    login: { screen: LoginScreen },
    onboard: { screen: OnboardScreen },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "onboard"
  }
)
```